# Hiding a counter if it is only displayed only one time

Tags: counters

I have two macros on my document. `\showcounter` increases a counter, then displays it. `\resetcounter` sets the counter back to "0".

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{counterone}
\setcounter{counterone}{0}
\newcommand{\showcounter}{
    \stepcounter{counterone}
    \arabic{counterone}
}
\newcommand{\resetcounter}{
\setcounter{counterone}{0}
}
\begin{document}
    \showcounter \showcounter \showcounter %A
    \resetcounter
    \showcounter \showcounter %B
    \resetcounter
    \showcounter %C
    \resetcounter
\end{document}
```

This creates a counter which increases until `\resetcounter` is used. However, in cases where `\showcounter` is only used one time before `\resetcounter` is used, I want no value to be shown.

- How can I hide the counter in such cases?

Update, to clarify, the output should appear like this:

> (A) 1, 2, 3
>
> (B) 1, 2
>
> (C)

In the last case, no "1" appeared, because the counter was not used again until the next `resetcounter`.

Comment: What you are asking for is rather tricky, and I don't think it is possible to do in a single pass, because you want the behaviour of `\showcounter` to depend on future info: you'll need to use the aux file to record that. However, it looks like you have a higher-level goal in mind, and that might be easier to do; what is it then?

Comment: The output appearance will be similar to the result of `inparaenum`, e.g. "This is a list: (1) fruit, (2) vegetables, (3) meat.", but where no number appears if only one item is listed. The `inparaenum` package will not work in my case, as the numbering flows from text, into macros, and back to text, so placing it in a list environment with `\begin` and `\end` would lead to too many problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now (from the first version of your question) I assume that the following solution might exceed your TeX's capacity (maybe try `lualatex` then?), but I guess I can't optimize it more.  An entry in the `aux` file is created *only* when actually resetting a counter with value 1; this entry defines an empty macro which is a signal to `\show...` *not* to display its argument.  (This probably could be memory-optimized so that instead of creating all these macros, we create one huge macro with a list of numbers.  This would most probably save memory, but increase the compilation time dramatically.  Dear wizards: please confirm whether I am right here;).)  An optional argument to `\show...` gives a macro (like `\alph` or `\arabic`) which actually displays the given counter; the user has to take care of any spaces.

Of course, you need two passes.  There's no indication of this fact (like "Run LaTeX again"), however, in the log file/terminal.

Now I'd be quite happy to turn this solution into package; one use case I'd imagine would be not to number a theorem in a paper when there's only one.  So any suggestions as to the user interface (including a better name for the now-idiotically-called macro `\defineoneshotcounter`) etc. are welcome.

Note: see Bruno Le Floch's comment below for a nice solution where `\counteronestyle` is the default instead of `arabic` (not put here in order not to clobber the code too much).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\defineoneshotcounter}[1]{%
  \newcounter{#1}
  \newcounter{#1@helper}
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname show#1\endcsname[1][\arabic]{%
    \stepcounter{#1}%
    \stepcounter{#1@helper}%
    \@ifundefined{#1@reset@\the\csname c@#1@helper\endcsname}{##1{#1}}{}%
  }
  \@namedef{reset#1}{%
    \ifnum\csname c@#1\endcsname=1\if@filesw
      \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\global\string\@namedef{#1@reset@\the\csname c@#1@helper\endcsname}{}%
      }%
    \fi\fi
    \setcounter{#1}{0}%
  }
}

\makeatother

\defineoneshotcounter{counterone}

\newcommand{\counteronestyle}[1]{\{\arabic{#1}\}}

\begin{document}
    \showcounterone \showcounterone \showcounterone
    \resetcounterone

    \showcounterone[\alph]\showcounterone[\alph]
    \resetcounterone

    \showcounterone
    \resetcounterone

    \showcounterone[\counteronestyle]\showcounterone[\counteronestyle]%
    \showcounterone[\counteronestyle]\showcounterone[\counteronestyle]
    \resetcounterone

    \showcounterone
    \resetcounterone

    \showcounterone \showcounterone
    \resetcounterone
\end{document}
```

Comment: When building a command with an optional argument, LaTeX creates several TeX macros, whose name is built from the command's name. So one `\let` is not enough to copy `\@tempa` _and the auxiliaries_. Instead you should simply do `\expandafter\newcommand\csname show#1\endcsname` etc. Also, it would seem more logical to use `\counteronestyle` by default. Perhaps with `\expandafter\newcommand\csname show#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter[\expandafter1\expandafter]\expandafter[\csname #1style\endcsname]{...}`?

Comment: Good point, how stupid of me!  I corrected this.  As for the second suggestion: nice trick, I'll put it in the package when I write it, here (for the sake of simplicity) I'll leave it that way.

Comment: To get the rerun warning, you could use the http://ctan.org/pkg/rerunfilecheck package, which notices changes in the aux file and gives a rerun warning.

Comment: There is a problem with your solution : see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44529/display-counters-only-if-it-is-used-at-least-two-times .

Answer (score 5):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{disccounters.sty}
\RequirePackage{keyval2e}
\long\def\gobble@to@relax#1\cpt@relax{}
\kve@definekeys[DC]{disccount}[disc@]{%
  format/\@firstofone,
  numbertype/\arabic/
    \ifescapedTF{#1}{%
      \xifinsetTF{,\detokenize{#1},}{%
        ,\detokenize{\arabic,\alph,\Alph},%
      }{}{%
        \@latex@error{Invalid number type '\detokenize{#1}'}\@ehc
      }%
    }{%
      \@latex@error{Number type '\detokenize{#1}' must be escaped}\@ehc
    },
}
\newcounter{disccounter@aux}
\BeforeStartOfDocument{%
  \ifdefTF\disccounter@hook{}{%
    \def\disccounter@hook{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*\discc@unter@aux{\the\numexpr\thedisccounter@aux-20000\relax}
\robust@def*\DefineDiscCounters{\cpt@testopt\disc@definecounters{}}
\robust@def*\disc@definecounters[#1]#2{%
  \cptexpandargonce{\kve@setafterdefaults[DC]{disccount}}{#1}%
  \setcounter{disccounter@aux}{0}%
  \docommalist{#2}{%
    \newcounter{##1}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname show##1\endcsname[1][]{%
      \stepcounter{##1}%
      \stepcounter{disccounter@aux}%
      \cptexpandargonce{\kve@setafterdefaults[DC]{disccount}}{####1}%
      \xifinsetTF{,##1@reset@\discc@unter@aux,}%
        {,\disccounter@hook,}{}{\disc@format{\disc@numbertype{##1}}}%
    }%
    \csn@def{reset##1}{%
      \ifnum\csname c@##1\endcsname=\@ne
        \xifinsetTF{,##1@reset@\discc@unter@aux,}{,\disccounter@hook,}{}{%
          \xdef\disccounter@hook{%
            \ifcsemptyTF\disccounter@hook{}{\disccounter@hook,}%
            ##1@reset@\discc@unter@aux
          }%
        }%
      \fi
      \setcounter{##1}{0}%
    }%
  }%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \gdef\string\disccounter@hook{\disccounter@hook}%
    }%
  \else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{File '\jobname.aux' not open}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*\discbraced[1]{{\tt\string{#1\string}}}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{disccounters}
\usepackage{color}
\DefineDiscCounters[numbertype=\arabic]{counterone,countertwo,counterthree}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
% If you hate the optional argument, you can use the plain \show... 
% (without argument), or put the optional arguments in a command (see later).
\item \showcounterone \showcounterone \showcounterone
  \resetcounterone
\item \showcounterone[numbertype=\alph]\showcounterone[numbertype=\alph]%
  \resetcounterone
\item \showcounterone
  \resetcounterone
\item \showcounterone[numbertype=\arabic]\showcounterone[numbertype=\arabic]%
  \showcounterone[numbertype=\arabic]\showcounterone[numbertype=\arabic]%
  \resetcounterone
\item \showcounterone
  \resetcounterone
\item \showcounterone[numbertype=\Alph]\showcounterone[numbertype=\Alph]
  \resetcounterone
\end{enumerate}

\begingroup
\color{red}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \showcountertwo \showcountertwo \showcountertwo
  \resetcountertwo
\item \showcountertwo[numbertype=\alph]\showcountertwo[numbertype=\alph]%
  \resetcountertwo
\item \showcountertwo
  \resetcountertwo
\item \showcountertwo[numbertype=\arabic]\showcountertwo[numbertype=\arabic]%
  \showcountertwo[numbertype=\arabic]\showcountertwo[numbertype=\arabic]%
  \resetcountertwo
\item \showcountertwo
  \resetcountertwo
\item \showcountertwo \showcountertwo
  \resetcountertwo
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\color{blue}
\def\tempa{numbertype=\alph,format=\discbraced}
\def\tempb{numbertype=\arabic,format=\discbraced}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \showcounterthree \showcounterthree \showcounterthree
  \resetcounterthree
\item \showcounterthree[\tempa]%
  \showcounterthree[numbertype=\Alph,format=\discbraced]%
  \resetcounterthree
\item \showcounterthree
  \resetcounterthree
\item \showcounterthree[\tempb]\showcounterthree[\tempb]%
  \showcounterthree[\tempb]\showcounterthree[\tempb]%
  \resetcounterthree
\item \showcounterthree
  \resetcounterthree
\item \showcounterthree \showcounterthree
  \resetcounterthree
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]