# Display counters only if it is used at least two times

Tags: counters

[In this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38561/hiding-a-counter-if-it-is-only-displayed-only-one-time), I've found one way to display one counter only if it is used at least two times.

The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work with two counters. Is there a way to allow this kind of feature ?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \makeatletter
        \newcommand{\defineoneshotcounter}[1]{%
            \newcounter{#1}
            \newcounter{#1@helper}
            \expandafter\newcommand\csname show#1\endcsname[1][\arabic]{%
                \stepcounter{#1}%
                \stepcounter{#1@helper}%
                \@ifundefined{#1@reset@\the\csname c@#1@helper\endcsname}{##1{#1}}{}%
            }
            \@namedef{reset#1}{%
                \ifnum\csname c@#1\endcsname=1\if@filesw
                \immediate\write\@auxout{%
                    \string\global\string\@namedef{#1@reset@\the\csname c@#1@helper\endcsname}{}%
                }%
                \fi\fi
                \setcounter{#1}{0}%
            }
        }
    \makeatother

    \defineoneshotcounter{FirstCounter}
    \newcommand{\FirstCounterStyle}[1]{\{\arabic{#1}\}}

    \defineoneshotcounter{SecundCounter}
    \newcommand{\SecundCounter}[1]{\{\arabic{#1}\}}

    \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}


\begin{document}

\section{First counter}

TEST : \showFirstCounter,
TEST : \showFirstCounter,
TEST : \showFirstCounter,
RESET : \resetFirstCounter

TEST : \showFirstCounter[\alph],
TEST : \showFirstCounter[\alph],
RESET : \resetFirstCounter

TEST : \showFirstCounter,
RESET : \resetFirstCounter

TEST : \showFirstCounter[\FirstCounterStyle],
TEST : \showFirstCounter[\FirstCounterStyle],
TEST : \showFirstCounter[\FirstCounterStyle],
TEST : \showFirstCounter[\FirstCounterStyle],
RESET : \resetFirstCounter

TEST : \showFirstCounter,
RESET : \resetFirstCounter

TEST : \showFirstCounter,
TEST : \showFirstCounter,
RESET : \resetFirstCounter


\section{Secund counter}

TEST : \showSecundCounter,
TEST : \showSecundCounter,
TEST : \showSecundCounter,
RESET : \resetSecundCounter

TEST : \showSecundCounter[\alph],
TEST : \showSecundCounter[\alph],
RESET : \resetSecundCounter

TEST : \showSecundCounter

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide the link where you took the solution from, so that we can see the original.

Comment: Just click on "This page" in my message.

Comment: It would help if you cold show the resulting output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second solution at [Hiding a counter if it is only displayed only one time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38561/hiding-a-counter-if-it-is-only-displayed-only-one-time) works for several counters defined at the same time or different times.

@Marc van Dongen: See projetmbc's output below.
[image]

I guess he's saying that the last `\showSecundCounter` shouldn't have produced any result, because it was called only once after `SecundCounter` was reset.

Comment: That's right Ahmed Musa.